# MVC AutocompleteFor not posting the SearchTextId field to the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a View that contains a Partial View. Within this partial view I do an autocomplete and the intention is that it populates an Id field.
When I look in ie developer tools, I notice that there are 2 hidden fields with the same name, one is populated with the correct value, the other with zero. It is zero which gets posted back and that is wrong.

So my View looks like

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SHP.WebUI.Models.PayrollViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SHP.Helpers" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Payroll
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Payroll", "Payroll", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmPayroll" }))
       {%>
        <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Payroll</legend>
            <%  Html.RenderPartial("EmployeeSelection", Model.HolidayYearViewModel); %>
        </fieldset>
              <%} %>
```

.
.
.

My partial view looks like;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.Models.HolidayYearViewModel>" %>

        <table class="groupBorder">
            <tr>
                <th>SelectYear</th>
                <th colspan="2">Enter 2 or more characters for "<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchText)%>" and select from the list.</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedHolidayYearId, Model.SelectListHolidayYear) %></td>
                <td><%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchText)%></td>
                <td><%: Html.AutocompleteFor(model => model.SearchText, controller: "Payroll",
                                            minLength: 2, maxResults: 10,
                                            htmlAttributes: new { style = "color:purple; width:500px;" })%>
                                <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SearchTextId)%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Get leave for this person" id="btnSubmit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

My controller looks like;

///  Payroll - user inputs an employee a date range to get their leave details.
    /// 
    ///  A view that allows the user to enter an employee and a date range
    /// from which they can view their holidays.
    /// 
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminAccounts, ManagerAccounts, ManagerIT")]
    public ActionResult Payroll()
    {
        return SessionObjects.PayrollSelectedEmployeeId == 0 ? 
                this.View(new PayrollViewModel()) : this.View(new PayrollViewModel(SessionObjects.PayrollSelectedEmployeeId));
    }

```
/// <summary> Payroll - This view shows a list of all the leave an employee has taken 
/// within the specified time period.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pvm">
/// The pvm - payroll view model contains the above list.
/// </param>
/// <returns>A view of the leave dates for the specified employee.
/// </returns>
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminAccounts, ManagerAccounts, ManagerIT")]
public ActionResult Payroll(PayrollViewModel pvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SessionObjects.HolidayYearViewModel = pvm.HolidayYearViewModel;
        if (pvm.HolidayYearViewModel.SearchTextId > 0)
        {
            SessionObjects.PayrollSelectedEmployeeId = pvm.HolidayYearViewModel.SearchTextId;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Payroll");
    }

    return View(pvm);
}
```

Autocomplete - which works, looks like

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchText, int maxResults)
{
    var filteredEmployees =
        Employee.GetAllCurrentEmployees().Where(x =>
            x.GetName().ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
        .Select(x => new IdTextItem { Text = x.GetAutocompleteName(), Id = x.EmployeeId })
        .Take(maxResults);
    return Json(filteredEmployees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My ViewModel looks like

```
   #region PayrollViewModel
    public class PayrollViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Period Start Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a start date")]
        public DateTime PeriodStartDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Period End Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter an end date")]
        public DateTime PeriodEndDate { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public List<Leave> LeaveList { get; set; }

        public HolidayYearViewModel HolidayYearViewModel { get; set; }

        public PayrollViewModel()
        {
            this.HolidayYearViewModel = SessionObjects.HolidayYearViewModel ?? new HolidayYearViewModel();
            var holidayYear = HolidayYear.GetHolidayYearById(HolidayYearViewModel.SelectedHolidayYearId);
            this.PeriodStartDate = holidayYear.HolidayYearStartDate;
            this.PeriodEndDate = holidayYear.HolidayYearEndDate;
        }
```

And the HolidayYearViewModel that is used in the PartialView looks like;

```
   public class HolidayYearViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HolidayYearViewModel"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public HolidayYearViewModel()
        {
            this.ListHolidayYear = new List<HolidayYear>();
            this.ListHolidayYear = HolidayYear.GetHolidayYearsInRange();
            this.SelectedHolidayYearId = HolidayYear.GetHolidayYearThisYear().HolidayYearId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets SelectedHolidayYearId.
        /// </summary>
        public int SelectedHolidayYearId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets ListHolidayYear - a list of the holiday year since the employee start Date
        /// </summary>
        public List<HolidayYear> ListHolidayYear { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets SearchText.
        /// </summary>
        [DisplayName("Get Employee")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string SearchText { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets SearchTextId.
        /// </summary>
        public int SearchTextId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets SelectListHolidayYear by converting the ListHolidayYear into a select list.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListHolidayYear
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ListHolidayYear.Select(item => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = item.HolidayYearName,
                    Value = item.HolidayYearId.ToString(),
                    Selected = item.HolidayYearId == this.SelectedHolidayYearId
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Any comments on how to improve the code would also be appreciated!

Comment: try to activate the autocomplete list, select an item and immediately click the submit button, don't type into the textbox after selecting